# Abstract Api Validation for Mobile number

Tags: php, api, abstract

Hello everyone I am trying to validate the mobile number using abstract api validation but I am stuck to check which number is valid and which number is not valid for this I write a code.

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://phonevalidation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=my_api&phone=14152007986');
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $data = json_decode($response, true);
        $check = (string)$data;
        if (strpos($check, 'true') == true)
        {
            echo "PhoneNo is valid";
        }
        if (strpos($check, 'false') == false)
        {
            echo "PhoneNo is invalid";
        }
```

In the above code the phone number is correct as I am giving the phone number as example but still its showing me PhoneNo is invalid can any one help me to create a logic for it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strpos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

So if the result is "true" string your validation with strpos should look like

```
if (strpos($check, 'true') !== false)
{
    echo "PhoneNo is valid";
} else
    echo "PhoneNo is invalid";
}
```

Because function returns false if the needle was not found.

Comment: Still it is showing Invalid after updating the logic

Comment: Can you attach result of var_dump($response) please?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem what i see is: You get a string then you parse the string into an array to cast it back into a string. so you can use your response right away. I don't know what the response looks like when it succeeds or fails. I only get `api key missing`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://phonevalidation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=my_api&phone=14152007986');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);        

if (strpos($response, 'true') == true)
{
    echo "PhoneNo is valid";
} else {
    echo "PhoneNo is invalid";
}
```